# Select values through many to many relationship in active record using "where"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get all the distict brands that have a part belonging to the category named car (category.name = "car"), through a many to many relationship.

Here are the models:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_parts
  has_many :parts, through: :brand_parts
end
```

-

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
end
```

-

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :brand_parts
  has_many :brands, through: :brand_parts
end
```

-

```
class BrandPart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :part
end
```

***Update: Answer below nailed it***

Here's This is what I've got so far:

```
Part.joins(:category).joins(:brands).where(category: {name: 'car'}).select(brands.name).distinct
```

The query it outputs (listed below) works GREAT in PG admin but through active record instead of being able to see the brand names, I just get a result set that looks like this:

```
#<Part id: nil>
#<Part id: nil>
#<Part id: nil>
```

Comment: Any chance you are using PostGreSQL..?

Comment: Perfect :) give me 5mn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has been tested by @newUserNameHere and actually working:

```
scope = Brand.joins(parts: :category).where(categories: { name: 'car' })
scope = scope.select('DISTINCT brands.name').order('brands.name')

brand_names_appearing_in_car_category = scope.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Had to play around with it a little to make it work (the distinct on threw it off), but here's the working query (all one line because this is a comment): Brand.joins(parts: :category).where(categories: { name: 'car' }).select("distinct brands.name").order('brands.name').map(&:name)

Comment: Forgot to change "Not tested" as it has been tested and is working :) Thanks again!